# Riemann Integral - Is there a formula to calculate the following sum?

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

I'm trying to calculate the integral of **f(x)= x^2** between **1** and **2** by taking the limit of the Riemann sum. I couldn't find a way to factor all the constants out of the summation so I'm stuck with this:
$$1/n^3\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n+i)^2$$
How do I go about it ?

Comment: Have you seen a formula for $$\sum_{k = 1}^n k^2\,?$$

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (n+i)^2=$ $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n}i^2-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2=$ $\frac{2n(2n+1)(4n+1)-n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ $\,$ - you can continue :-)

Comment: Yeah I did @DanielFischer.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the leap from $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n+i)^2$$ to $$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$$ @user90369 ? I fail to observe the connection between the two expressions. Is that a formula that I have to know of ?

Comment: It's what *Daniel Fischer* has mentioned and you have answered that you know this formula: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ - and about the sums: It's the same to start with $n+1$ and to end with $2n$ or to start with $1$ and end with $2n$ and then substract a sum where you start from $1$ and end with $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I tried working my way out using the distributive rule of summation:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(n+i)^2=n^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}1+2n\sum_{i=1}^{n}i+\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2\\=n^3+\frac{2n^2(n+1)}{2}+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\=\frac{14n^3+9n^2+n}{6}$$
And now I can multiply it by the constant term I factored out earlier, which is 1/n^3 :
$$\frac{14n^3+9n^2+n}{6n^3}$$
All I have to do now is to take this sum to the limit:
$$\int_{1}^{2}f(x)dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_{i})\Delta x=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{14n^3+9n^2+n}{6n^3}=7/3$$

Comment: That's right. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^n(n+i)^2 &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(1+i/n)^2\\
&\rightarrow\int_0^1(1+x)^2 dx\\
&=\int_1^2 x^2 dx.
\end{align*}